# How can I add an option [ Preferred Tick Mark ] in edit page to set that page as home page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want the latest page to be set as home page always. So while creating a new page I would like to keep an option in the edit page to set that page as static home page which will overwrite old static home page setting. So that user does not need to go to Settings->Reading to set static home page again after creating new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option for display front page in word press which key is "page_on_front" and it's being store home page id in wp_option table.

You can use meta data in page section in which if check box to be checked for new page, during update page update value in option table for "page_on_front" by current page id.

It would automatically update home page by latest post in which you check checkbox.

Comment: Great. 

Is there any way get lastly created or latest page title or page id, not current page id. 

I used this code:

Comment: yes, with the help of get_posts you can get post list order by descending and you can get last post id and related details.

Comment: Great, I have solved it. Cheerz :) 

Another problem, How can I auto fill the page title? I want to add dynamically date and time in the title of the page while creating a new page.

Comment: you can skip page title during add new page and append date and time during insert new page functionality as page title so it will automatically set as page title.

Comment: Yes exactly. I did  and It works. Thanks 

But I want to  generate title right after pressing "Add New Page" not after publishing. Any Idea please?

Or Alternative solution may be hiding the title field. Though It's bullshit solution. Ha ha

Comment: yes , you can hide title field by css as well , as is is not mandatory..for that you can use hook and apply custom css as well

Comment: Or you can do further custom by pass date/time in to js and append value by class/ id reference to title text box value via java script / jquery.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can select your Home page by going into 
settings -> Reading here you can select the page you need to display as your home page.

Comment: I know that and I already said it on description. I don't want that. I want the lastly created page will be my home page automatically. Got it?